# How to COUNT Column not NULL into same table?

Tags: mysql, count, multiple-columns

How to count a table column that not Null or Zero and Insert the result into "Count" column like table down below in Mysql?

```
 column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | Count
    3        2          4         2        4
    2        2          3         0        3     
    3        0          5         2        3
    0        0          2         3        2
    0        0          6         2        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is simply using `case` statement:

Edit:

For update `cnt` column in your `table_name`, you can use:

```
update table_name 
set cnt = (case when column1 is null or column1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end + 
           case when column2 is null or column2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
           case when column3 is null or column3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
           case when column4 is null or column4 = 0 then 0 else 1 end)
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake and I've been edit the question, yeah you code is showing a result, but what if there is zero on the table, and I don't want it to be counted, I'm trying is '0' or null but I got an error.

Comment: insert? Do you mean `update` another column with this `count` value

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    CT.Column1,
    CT.Column2,
    CT.Column3,
    CT.Column4,
    (
        select count(*)
        from (values (CT.column1), (CT.column2), (CT.column3), (CT.column4)) as v(col)
        where v.col is not null
    ) as Count
from customtable as CT
```

Comment: I'm editing the question a little bit to be more easily understand, but I trying your code but showing error at
`from (values (CT.column1), (CT.column2), (CT.column3), (CT.column4)) as v(col)`

Answer (score 0):

first in your table on your 3rd line the expected count is 3 right ?
A dirty way of doing this would be to sum the integer values of the test is the column NULL (boolean as int is 1 or 0 ):

```
SELECT
Column1, Column2, Column3,  Column4,
 (CAST(column1 is not null AS SIGNED INTEGER) +
    CAST(column2 is not null AS SIGNED INTEGER) +
    CAST(column3 is not null AS SIGNED INTEGER) + 
    CAST(column4 is not null AS SIGNED INTEGER)) as count
FROM (
    SELECT 3 as column1,2 as column2,4 as column3,2 as column4
    union select 2,2,3,NULL
    union select 3,NULL,5,2
    union select NULL,NULL,2,3
    union select NULL,NULL,6,2
) as YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

update  set =sum(COUNT(*)-COUNT(column1) + COUNT(*)-COUNT(column2) + COUNT(*)-COUNT(column3) + COUNT(*)-COUNT(column4)) where =;